# What is the relationship between something magnetic and unpaired electrons?

Tags: physical-chemistry, magnetism

I don't get how some elements are magnetic. Can someone please explain the relationship between something magnetic and unpaired electrons?

Why is cobalt magnetic?

Comment: Pretty sure hw questions need to have an "attempt" so I'll give you some suggestions to look at and maybe you could incorporate them in your question so we can answer it. You might want to look at the concepts of "ferromagnetism", "paramagnetism" and "diamagnetism". It has to do with the electron spin. After reading it, you'll probably get it. Cobalt is considered ferromagnetic. Also, have you seen a trend in magnetism (hint hint, d and p). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are five forms of magnetic behavior. **Ferromagnetism** is when a material is attracted to a magnetic field and can spontaneously hold a magnetic field alone (the typical form of magnetism).  **Paramagnetism** is when a material is attracted to a magnetic field but cannot spontaneously hold a magnetic field alone (the attraction may be too weak to observe practically).  **Diamagnetism** is a material that expels magnetic fields (essentially non-magnetic). there is also **ferrimagnetic** and **anti-ferromagnetic** but though these are interesting they not incredibly relevant to the answer.

Electrons form the magnetic fields of materials.  If a metal's atom have unpaired electrons the metal can attract a magnetic field.  If all of the electrons are paired in opposite spin orbitals then the spins cancel each other out and no response to a magnetic field is observed.

Cobalt has unpaired electrons making it at minimum demonstrate **paramagnetic** behavior. It is however able to hold a magnetic field making it **ferromagnetic**.  Most metals have unpaired electron and are **paramagnetic** (for example: aluminum, zirconium, titanium, magnesium and potassium)  **Ferromagnetic** metals become **paramagnetic** at elevated temperatures and inversely many **paramagnetic** metals become ferromagnetic at low temperatures.